# How to update database entity in java play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am new on play framework java, i am doing on store management system and i need to know how to use class calculation if i sell s.thing to the client from store A to client X , when i check remaining quantity in the store A i can find that the quantity was updated( reduced) according to the quantity sold to the client.

model method  used to sell a product to client X:

```
 public static void save(Customer_one customer) {


             customer.save();

}
```

*controller method used to sell a product to client X :*

public static Result sell( ) {

```
    Form<Customer_one> formData_one = Form.form(Customer_one.class).bindFromRequest();
 Customer_one.save(formData_one.get());
   return ok("product was been sold successfully");

}
```

The following method is used to check remaining product in the store A

```
   public static Result RemainingQuantity(){
         Form<Store> taskData = form(Store.class);
        return ok(views.html.store.render(Store.bal(),    taskData));
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use class calculation in java play framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666625/how-to-use-class-calculation-in-java-play-framework)

Comment: Sorry ,I was not detected that ,How to use class calculation in java play framework ,is posted  ,but the idea is the same

Comment: It is still somewhat unclear what you want to achieve. How is the balance in class `Store` calculated? What is the purpose of the `save` method in `Customer_one` class? Why not call `save()` directly?

Comment: The balance in   `store`  is calculated as `sum`   ,the purpose of     `save()` method in     `customer_one` i want to use it to `subtract ` some quantity of product from   `Store`  when is given to the client.

Comment: Just what i need to know is the query i can use and work like a trigger  in `Customer_one` when i send data in **client table** , **Store table** become **updated** by reducing stored quantity in it.

Comment: Post your `Store` class so that I can help building the query

Comment: **Store class**       `@Entity
public class Store extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public int amount=0;
    public static Finder<Long, Store> find = new Finder(Long.class, Store.class);
    public static void recharge(Store storedb) {
    storedb.save();
        }
    public static long bal() {
        final String sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM store";
        SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
        SqlRow row = sqlQuery.findUnique();
        return row.getInteger("total");
    }}`

Comment: And what is the relationship between `Store` and `Customer_one`? Somehow you need to know which `Store` instance is going to be updated.